# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal' with python source code installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, redhat

I have installed python3.7 on redhat machine by compiling source code but I have a problem when dealing with pip3. I have made this steps after installation:

```sh
sudo ln /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3

sudo ln /usr/local/bin/pip3.7 /usr/bin/pip3
```

python3 -- version gives Python 3.7.3

But I have this errors by running these commands :

```sh
python3 -m pip install requests
```

gives **/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed**

```sh
pip3 install requests
```

gives **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'**

Comment: what is the output of `pip3 --version` ? same like above?

Comment: same error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Comment: Then probably you have to reinstall the `pip`

Comment: Ok so how to install pip3 and link it with python 3.7 version on red hat ?

Comment: Please check answer.

Answer (score 40):

Try to reinstall the `pip` as follows :

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Comment: I have permission denied first then when I change to root mode it's succefully installed but when quit root mode I get same errors

Comment: @WajihKatrou : And what is the output of `pip3 --version`?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Comment: So it means `pip` itself not reinstalled properly.

Comment: Could send me a proper installation for both python3.7 and pip for python3.7 please

Comment: try with root only, because you have forcefully installed for root user.

Comment: Even if you've gotten the get-pip.py, the script itself seems to require being connected to the Internet, so it is not a panacea.

Answer (score 11):

I have had the same issue, eventually found out the I have a version of pip install in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\anaconda` and it was defaulting to this.

I identified this by using

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

In a command prompt.

Deleted the anaconda folder and it finally works!

Comment: BTW, this is what fixed it for me on Amazon Linux after I upgraded from Python 3.6.2 to 3.7.6

Comment: Goog solution. I had similar issue when tried to upgrade pip but installation failed due to missing permissions. The result was uninstalled actual version and failed upgrade to up-to-date version.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.9 in a Mac. This helps me to identify the problem is from the old version of python.  Uninstall the old version fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on a Unix distribution update pip with sudo:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: `/Users/user/venv/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: @alper Using the command ```module load python``` first fixed that issue for me.

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury: Where are you using that command?

Answer (score 1):

To update pip, run:

```py
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Trying this, I get: `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`