# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

[image: 1]

I can't use pip and I don't know why.

The error I get is shown below:

```
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

If I try `py -3.8 -m pip install` I get
`D:\Python\python.exe: No module named pip`.

If I use get-pip nothing happens.

If I try to upgrade pip nothing happens.

Comment: Did you re-install python and all tools ?

Comment: Did you try using pip3?

Comment: tafhim | no i don´t have re-install python and all tools maby i can find another way

Comment: yovel cohen | Yes i did

Comment: How did you install `python`? Was this error there from the beginning or did it appear after you did something specific?

Comment: @Amir You shouldn't need to reinstall all your tools. Try just reinstalling python itself and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.\_internal' with python source code installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361133/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pip-internal-with-python-sour)

Answer (score 52):

Following [pip installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), try this on Windows

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

This command activates pip.

Ref. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

After this you can upgrade

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or, on Windows

```
py -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: C:\Users\Amir>python -m ensurepip

C:\Users\Amir>python -m pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                            Nothing happened

Comment: Amir, call the python executable by its full pathname or add its installation directory to the system variable PATH.

Comment: I tried this and got, "no module named ensurepip"

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` uninstalls pip for me lmao python pls .-. `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` `Uninstalling pip-22.0.4`

Comment: @Snowcrash Why are you using Python2 when it is end-of-life? `pip` can upgrade itself, therefore why it is listed twice. And short-args with single dash vs two for long-opts are CLI semantics, not a Python issue... The Python installer "ensures Python"... Not all OS come with Pip installed, therefore why it needs "ensured" via code that it does come with.

Comment: @OneCricketeer because Python and Pip is hard to upgrade. e.g. on the old Mac I occasionally use, the system Python is 2.7 (from memory) and no upgrade path is offered. So, you end up upgrading in userspace but, if you haven't aliased correctly, it's easy to end up using the system python.

Comment: @Snowcrash I see. However Mac system python won't let you run `get-pip.py` without `sudo` (which should be avoided). It is not "hard to upgrade" IMO, following https://python.org/downloads . `pip` has come with Python installation since version 3.4. Otherwise, people often use Anaconda or `pyenv` + `brew` to install those. Where, you should almost always prefer `python3` alias over just `python`

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. But in my case, when I was upgrading the `pip` version the new version stopped installing (upgrading) before the older version successfully uninstalled. After searching 4 or 5 sites I found:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

I was able to use the `pip` command and also this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Debian/Ubuntu/Linux Mint and derivatives users**

Install pip using APT:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what OS you are using and what errors you got when using get-pip, but I had similar issue on Ubuntu20 and this solved it:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Credit: @Benjamin's answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal

Comment: Or, you could `apt install python3-pip` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

A suggestion, try to use anaconda or venv to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found that `python -m ensurepip` just told me that the pip scripts were already installed.  So what I did was delete the 2 pip directories under `C:\Users\[user_id]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages`, then run `python -m ensurepip` again.  That fixed it for me.