# Unable to install pylint with pip in python 3.9

Tags: python, pip

I am starting to use VS Code, but pylint is not installed and it gives me an error.
I try to install pylint using pip, but it gives me an error code.

````
Collecting pylint
  Using cached pylint-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (325 kB)
Collecting astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0
  Using cached astroid-2.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
Collecting colorama
  Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting isort<6,>=4.2.5
  Using cached isort-5.6.4-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.4.*
  Using cached lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
  WARNING: Requested lazy-object-proxy==1.4.* from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/3f/a3d687f83c7d44970f70ff0400677746c8860b11f0c08f6b4e07205f0cdc/lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3.tar.gz#sha256=f3900e8a5de27447acbf900b4750b0ddfd7ec1ea7fbaf11dfa911141bc522af0 (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint), but installing version 0.0.0
ERROR: Requested lazy-object-proxy==1.4.* from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/3f/a3d687f83c7d44970f70ff0400677746c8860b11f0c08f6b4e07205f0cdc/lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3.tar.gz#sha256=f3900e8a5de27447acbf900b4750b0ddfd7ec1ea7fbaf11dfa911141bc522af0 (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) has different version in metadata: '0.0.0'```
````

Comment: Can you do `pip install lazy-object-proxy --upgrade` first and than try to install pylint

Comment: I tried, but i got the same error message

Comment: You can also try to install an older sub-version from the `lazy-object-proxy==1.4.*` series first.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. It worked when I installed the 1.4 version of lazy-object-proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug of pip for now, see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9203. The pip does something wrong in its package-dependencies handling. And there is a workaround listed in this issue, use `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`. And be noted: `This will work until we release pip 21.0`.

So run `pip install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver pylint` will resolve this problem. This works for me on win10, finally I got `lazy-object-proxy 0.0.0` and `pylint 2.6.0` installed, though 0.0.0 is kinda weird.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with Python 3.9 & Pylint.
Even when I tried the answers given here, nothing worked. I kept on getting Error messages.

**All my issues where fixed by doing the following:**

1. Uninstalled Python 3.9.1
2. Installed Python 3.7.9 - *(Remember to click the box **add to PATH**)*
3. Verifying Python Installation:
   3.1 `python --version`, This should give you `Python 3.7.9`
   If it doesn't and you get an Error, you need to configure your **PATH**, here is a video on how to fix that:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWxQG70GqT4&list=PL914uJ85wHwJ4WYvHEhPHSgG2oyi7Azat&index=11&ab_channel=KyleCook
4. Verifying `pip` Installation:
   4.1 `pip --version` *(I got another Error here again)*
   i.e.: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' python3**
   I fixed that by:
   4.1.1 `python -m ensurepip`
   4.1.2 `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
   Ref: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561218/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pip-python3)
5. Install Pylint for Python 3.6+:
   5.1 `pip install pylint --upgrade`
   Ref: https://pypi.org/project/pylint/

This worked for me.