# pip installing python packages for the wrong version

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use pip to install some packages that I need, but I came across a problem. My default version of python is python3.10 but when I try using pip to install packages for it, it installes them for python3.8

This is the output of `pip --version`:

```
pip 22.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Is there a way to change this so that I can install packages for python 3.10?

When I try to run `python3 -m pip --version` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

Comment: How can you call python from the command line? If it's `python3` then you're best off using `python3 -m pip --version`

Comment: See [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: I've edited my response with the output of your suggestion.

Comment: Do you use python from the command line? How do you typically call the 3.10 version?

Comment: with just `python3`, this calls the 3.10 version

Comment: You'll want to install pip (solutions for Mac and Ubuntu in answers to [ImportError: No module named pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363022/importerror-no-module-named-pip)), then probably still want to use `python3 -m pip` commands.

Comment: I've also just seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562956/5358968) which suggests `python -m ensurepip` which might help.

Comment: @Steve `ensurepip` will not work with python version less than 3.4 as it was introduced with version 3.4

Comment: @PrashantMaurya so it should work fine with python 3.10 then

Comment: @Steve `ensurepip` shouldn't work with python 3.10 as it was introduced in the later versions

Comment: @PrashantMaurya `python3.10` means major version 3, minor version 10 - 3.10 is currently the latest stable release (released 2021) and more recent than 3.4 (released 2014, no longer maintained).

Comment: @Steve you are right, my fault

Answer (score 0):

Download `get-pip.py` file from any of the following options:

- Download it manually from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
- Download it from terminal/cmd using: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
- Download it from terminal/cmd using: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

Then run the command `python3 get-pip.py`, it will install pip in the python version invoked by python3(which is 3.10 as you have stated).
Install packages using command `python3 -m pip install package_name`

Comment: When I try this I get this error: `zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available`

Comment: At what command you are getting this error?

Comment: try this to install zilb: `sudo apt install -y zlib1g-dev zlibc`

Comment: at the `python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: I installed zlib with the command you suggested but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @WholesomeGhost the following issue might be helpful: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1919

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said you can call the desired python version with the command `python3`, it's best to call pip via

```bash
python3 -m pip
```

This ensures you're installing packages to the correct version ([Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/5358968)).

To install pip if it's missing, you can use [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562956/5358968))

```bash
python3 -m ensurepip
```

It's probably worth mentioning [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which lets you create a local python environment to keep your packages separate for different projects.

Comment: I get the same error here as mentioned in the answer above.